# How best can I write this query?

Tags: sql, ado.net, nested-datalist

I am currently working on an Online Food Ordering App where Many restaurants offer different menu that belongs to a particular MenuCategory. which means that I have

```
restaurant

menu(contains a foreign key to the MenuCategory)

menucategory,

restaurant_menu(contains foreign keys to menu and restaurant).
```

Now I want to fetch all the menu for each restaurant by categories so that I can display them using nested repeater control. I have been able to display the categories of menu offered by each restaurant.

How can I fetch the menu details for each category for a particular restaurant  using ADO.NET technology. The ER diagram is shown in the image below:

[image]

and the expected output should be similar to the one found here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/showing-category-and-subcategory-using-nested-repeater-in-as/

Comment: Update your question with your actual table structures, some sample data and your expected output. Also, provide the query that you're currently using.

Comment: It seems that nobody wants to help me out here.

Comment: I've just edited your question to improve the formatting. I'm not sure that your first picture is working, it won't load for me. Also, let us know the actual field names that you're using

Comment: I will really appreciate if  someone could help me out with how to write the queries to fetch all the menus by category and display them using nested repeater control in ASP.NET. I am new here and will appreciate any help from you guys.